# programmatically change ListPreference options and keep the change permanent

Tags: android, xml, listpreference

I saw a couple of posts about changing the options programmatically but none of them say if that change is permanent.

What I want is basically to change the xml file that contains these options, the only problem is I dont know where it is or if it kept and read from everytime the app comes up.

**Clarification:** I have a ListPreference which is created from xml file, its arrays of entries and values are also defined in an xml with certain options.
I would like to programmatically change these options (delete/add)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your post `clear`? **What** do you want to change? **How** are you supposed to change that? By **options** do you mean `SharedPReferences`?

Comment: Added clarification, please look at it

Comment: read PreferenceManager docs

Comment: I did:
1. I didnt find anythin usefull there, can you please point me in the right direction?
2. I found some other things the might be what I need in Preference but it doesnt say if the change is persistent or the next time I run the app it will go back to the entries defined in the xml...

Comment: The xml file for your Preferences is **immutable**

Comment: Do you know where are all these xmls are saved?

Comment: follow this: PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences

Comment: I know what sharedpreferences are, but they save my **choices** I want to change what I am able to choose to what I chose.